# Alternatives for shape-rendering of SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm drawing a SVG path with rounded corners.

When using crispEdges rendering, the corners look like pixels (left).

But without crispEdges the lines blur (right):

[image]

Is there a way to make the path more precise but without pixels at the corners?

P.S.: I've tried other values of shape-rendering, it's the same.

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);
svg.setAttribute("width", 2000 + "px");
svg.setAttribute("height",1000 + "px");

var svgPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
svgPath.setAttribute('stroke', 'blue');
svgPath.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
svgPath.setAttribute('d','M 350 350 L 350 400 C 350 403, 352 409, 358 410 L 450 410' );
svg.appendChild(svgPath);

svgPath.setAttribute('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges');
```

Comment: [These](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) are your options. You're either gonna have anti-aliasing, or pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `stroke-width` is `1` and since we are rendering with what seems to be a 1:1 ratio of the SVG unit space to the browser pixel space, you could consider offsetting the coordinates of the lines by `0.5` so that the drawing of the stroke is aligned perfectly to the pixel grid, thus reducing the blurring on the straight lines on low pixel-ratio screens.

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
document.body.appendChild(svg);
svg.setAttribute("width", 2000 + "px");
svg.setAttribute("height",1000 + "px");

var svgPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
svgPath.setAttribute('stroke', 'blue');
svgPath.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
svgPath.setAttribute('d','M 350.5 350.5 L 350.5 400.5 C 350 403, 352 409, 358.5 410.5 L 450 410.5' );
svg.appendChild(svgPath);
```